# How to customize nested components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

How to customize nested components?

I'm building React Native app with Redux.
I have three screens in my app that render list of users.

Follower/Following should show `FollowButton`:

```
<FollowersContainer> 
  <UserList onFollow={func} onUnfollow={func} users={[...]}>
    <UserCard user={user} onFollow={func} onUnfollow={func}>
      <FollowButton onFollow={func} onUnfollow={func} isFollowing={bool} userId={string} />
    </UserCard>
  </UserList>
</FollowersContainer>
```

Ask question screen should show `AskButton`:

```
<AskQuestionContainer> 
  <UserList onAsk={func} users={[...]}>
    <UserCard user={user} onAsk={func}>
      <AskButton onPress={onAsk} />
    </UserCard>
  </UserList>
</AskQuestionContainer>
```

Search Results should not show any button

```
<SearchResultsContainer> 
  <UserList users={[...]}>
    <UserCard user={user} />
  </UserList>
</SearchResultsContainer>
```

As you can see, all three screens uses `UserList` and `UserCard` components.

Currently `UserList` and `UserCard` needs to know about `onFollow` `onUnfollow` and `onAsk` actions and how to pass them around.

This can get complicated and not very flexible.

Ideally I want to do something like:

```
<UserList 
  rowComponent={
    <UserCard button={<FollowButton />} />
  }
/>
```

But how do I pass the actions from the top level component into the actual button? and How do I know which actions to pass?

I could use `connect` on the actual buttons to pass them the actions directly but I prefer these components stay pure and flexible.

Any suggestion on how to solve it in a clean way?

Thanks,
Ran.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass components as a prop.

```js
render() {
  var passedButton = (<FollowButtton />);
  var row = (<UserCard button={passedButton} />);
  return (
    <UserList rowComponent={row}/>
  );
};
```

Comment: I know I could do that, the problem FollowButton needs to get his props from UserList and I can't find a way to pass these props without the parent know about all of his grandchildren